# SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView() getting called for first 4 items many times when changing layout of listitem

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListView and a SimpleCursorAdapter subclass that display data from an SQLite database . I have customized my adapter in such a way that when I click a listitem it expands/collapses to show more details. Everything is working fine, but I discovered a weird behaviour that's using unnecessary processing.

Let's say I have 200 items in my list, all of which are in a collapsed state (this just means that some of the TextViews inside them have visibility="gone"). Now I scroll down the list to item number 100. bindView() gets called for each item, with _id=1, _id=2, ... , _id=99, _id=100 as expected. Now I click item 100 and expand it (change some of it's TextView's to visibility="visible"). One would expect bindView() to get called for _id=100 and perhaps some of the surrounding items like _id=98, _id=99, _id=101, _id=102 because the ListView needs to be redrawn. But here's the weird part - bindView() gets called for _id=1, _id=2, _id=3, _id=4 (which are of course way off the screen). And that's not all - it does this twice, so we've got 8 bindView() calls for the first 4 items in the ListView, which are not anywhere close to being displayed on the screen. The surrounding items don't get a bindView() call, not even item number 100 gets one!

Since everything is working as it should I can live with this, but I'm really curious a as to why this strange behaviour is going on. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: I am running into this issue as well, except it's the first 10 items (which is about how many rows are visible on the screen at once). Did you ever get an answer to this?